# How to fix a crowbar mesh deformation problem

Tags: 3d-meshes, modding, source-engine

I am having a problem exporting my model to Garry's Mod.
Every time i compile the model in crowbar it comes out deformed like this
[image]

when the model is really suppose to look like this
[image]

how do I fix this is there something wrong with the collision?
I am also ready to provide whatever files/information are needed to solve this problem.
I should also mention that the mesh has multiple objects from each sphere that are joined but not connected. 
I went to the arqade for this at first but they said it was offtopic and that I should come here instead.

Comment: is there not enough information? just ask for the files that are needed just help me